# SoapClient calls keep returning null

Tags: php, soap

I've been banging my head on this for awhile now, and I keep getting nowhere.

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => 1));
print_r($client->__getFunctions());
$params->param1 = $cust;
$params->param2 = "1f0de966909641061b729d383bd41bb2f0c3f4db";
$response = $client->ValidateLicenseKey($params);
print_r($params);
print_r($response);
echo "Last Request: ".$client->__getLastRequest();
echo "Last Response: ".$client->__getLastResponse();
```

The output of that is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ValidateLicenseKeyResponse ValidateLicenseKey(ValidateLicenseKey $parameters)
    [1] => CreateProviderResponse CreateProvider(CreateProvider $parameters)
    [2] => SetHardwareProfileResponse SetHardwareProfile(SetHardwareProfile $parameters)
    [3] => UpdateCurrentVersionResponse UpdateCurrentVersion(UpdateCurrentVersion $parameters)
    [4] => SoftwareUpdateAvailableResponse SoftwareUpdateAvailable(SoftwareUpdateAvailable $parameters)
    [5] => GetSoftwareUpdateResponse GetSoftwareUpdate(GetSoftwareUpdate $parameters)
)
stdClass Object
(
    [param1] => satsys
    [param2] => 1f0de966909641061b729d383bd41bb2f0c3f4db
)
stdClass Object
(
    [ValidateLicenseKeyResult] => 
)
Last Request: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:ValidateLicenseKey/></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
Last Response: <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><ValidateLicenseKeyResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><ValidateLicenseKeyResult>false</ValidateLicenseKeyResult></ValidateLicenseKeyResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope></pre>
```

Why on earth print_r suggest that the return is null? This is just a simple call that checks to see whether a key is in the database or not. None of the other functions return results either. Can someone explain what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return is not null, it is `false`. Use `var_dump` to see variable types more clearly. The parsed response object is valid representation of the response XML.

Comment: Or, like me, you're var_dumping the wrong variable. *facepalm*